# Use attribute selector to change panels in a panel stack (Microstrategy)

Tags: microstrategy

So I have an attribute selector that currently changes the view of a grid based on the attribute passed to that grid.  I also have a panel stack directly below the grid, with panels that hold iframes, which needs to be changed as the user selects an attribute in the selector.  In other words, as the user selects an attribute from the selector, the panels would changes and show the new iframe. Is there a way I can somehow control the panel stack from an attribute selector?

The panel stack contains iframes , and each panel has an iframe with a specific URL source.  What would be great is if I could somehow pass the attribute to the URL so that the iframe in a SINGLE panel could change based on the selection made in the attribute selector.   For example, if I set the URL source of the iframe to "/servername/microstrategy/asp/{&attribute}.html" and had my html files stored in the correct folder.  But there doesnt seem to be a way to pass the selected attribute to the source URL of the iframe.

The only thing I can think of is to somehow access the "code-behind" for the click event so that it BOTH changes the grid as usual, AND causes the panel stack to change panels.

Is there something in the Web Editor or SDK/Eclipse IDE that would allow me to access such logic?  Or is there some cool work-around that would allow an attribute selector to change the panels shown in a panel stack.

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 1):

Kind of old question, but AFAIK there is no way to do it. You should probably go with text-boxes and use them as selectors. Maybe with view filters you could achieve something similar...